# How to use DateTimeFormatter to get time only?

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

I am making an appointment app and am trying to get only the time of the appointment to fill into a combobox. So far I was able to get just the date, but now I am having trouble with receiving just the time. It shows up as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm in the combobox. The code in question are the last two statements. The modifyDate successfully prints only the date, but I just can't seem to figure out how to separate the date off and  print just the time. I tried to create another DateTimeFormatter with HH:mm but that did not work. Thank you so much!

This setAppointment is what puts the data from an existing appointment into the modify screen:

```
public void setAppointment(Appointment appointment, int index) {
    selectedAppointment = appointment;
    selectedIndex = index;

    Appointment newAppointment = (Appointment) appointment;

    DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");

    this.modifyContactNameText.setText(newAppointment.getContact());
    this.modifyTitleText.setText((newAppointment.getTitle()));
    this.modifyURLText.setText((newAppointment.getUrl()));
    this.modifyTypeText.setText((newAppointment.getType()));
    this.modifyDescriptionComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getDescription()));
    this.modifyLocationComboBox.setValue((newAppointment.getLocation()));
    this.modifyDate.setValue(LocalDate.parse(newAppointment.getStart(), format));
    this.modifyStartComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(newAppointment.getStart(), format));
    this.modifyEndComboBox.getSelectionModel().select(newAppointment.getEnd(), format));
```

Comment: What `newAppointment.getStart()` return?

Comment: it will return a date + time from the database. Similar to "2020-03-27 11:00", getEnd will return the same date, but an end time.

Comment: You shouldn’t keep start and end times as `String` in your `Appointment` class. Keep proper date-time objects such as `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` (depending on exact requirements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you need to convert `String` to `LocalDateTime` and then extract the time part using another formater:

```
...
DateTimeFormatter timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm");
String time = LocalDateTime.parse(newAppointment.getStart(), format)
             .format(timeFormat);
```

Or much better:

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalDateTime.parse(newAppointment.getStart(), format)
    .toLocalTime();
```

**Output**

```
11:00
```